# get-counter with locale independent IDs

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

I am trying to access the following counter-path via the cmdlet `get-counter` in a locale-independent way:

```
\Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes
```

I followed the instructions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538299/access-windows-performance-counters-in-a-locale-independent-way) to archive this. And so I looked up the two IDs for the counter-path in the registry and got `\4\58`
But unfortunately this path won't work. I always get the error-message

```
The specified performance-indicator could not be found
```

The path from the other thread `\238(_Total)\6` works perfectly fine! But for my path I can only get `\4\*` to list all counters in the set.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

@Chris,

PowerShell Magazine carried an article on this a while ago.

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/07/19/querying-performance-counters-from-powershell/

Tobias showed a way to translate counter names to ID numbers.

Comment: ok, the specified function "Get-PerformanceCounterLocalName" does work indeed. But I still don't understand why the path `\4\58` doesn't. This would be much easier because there is no extra function needed. Could you have a try on this path?

Comment: Make sure to replace the registry key in function `Get-PerformanceCounterID` by `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009` so you can query IDs from the english names.